# Onenote Producing Jagged Pen Ink on some areas of page Surface Pro 3

Tags: microsoft-onenote, microsoft-surface, microsoft-surface-pro

Windows Journal works fine. This is only in OneNote

[image: sample]

Anyone know the issue?

Comment: This can be reproduced on any areas of the screen or just certain areas?

Comment: @Ramhound Just on the left side of a page in onenote, and the issue is only present in OneNote, no other application. So only a specific part of the page, and only this specific app.

Comment: I honestly don't see a difference...

Comment: @Ramhound try looking at the words 'are', 'someone', and even 'you'. I know my writing is a little messy however these look almost shaky and not as smooth flowing as my other bits of text are. I can assure you I don't shake like that when I write.